# Ruby on Rails Separate admin folder, controllers and layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise, controllers

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I want to have following structure for admin section.

1. app/controller/admin/admin_controller.rb and all other admin section controller under app/controller/admin/ folder
2. app/views/layout/admin/admin.html.erb to keep separate html layout for admin section

At the same time i want to use Devise Gem for admin and front end user authentication.

I executed `rails g devise:views admin`, `rails generate devise Admin` and `rails g controller admin/home index` command that created views, model and controller for admin user. Now what routes and other setting i need to add so that ruby could understand that if i type http://localhost:3000/admin/ then i should be redirected to http://localhost:3000/admins/sign_in/ page and after entering correct admin credentials i should redirected to index method of controllers/admin/home_controller.rb

is it also possible to keep singular convention of Devise admin views like `admin/sign_in` instead of `admins/sign_in` ?

I have searched a lot but could not get relevant help. Please provide steps to achieve above.

Thanks in advance.

This is how route file looks like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    get 'home/index'
  end

  devise_for :admins

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: "home#index"
end
```

When i type http://localhost:3000/admin/ then i get below error

[image]

Comment: show your routes file, are you getting any errors with the way you are trying to do things ?

Comment: @Subhash, thanks for your quick response. I have added code of my route file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not have root route defined for `/admin`.

I have the same URL convention routes in one of the apps and `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Admin part
  devise_for :admins, path: '/admin'

  scope module: :admin, path: '/admin', as: 'admin' do
    root to: 'home#index'
  end

  # Redirect app root to client part
  root to: redirect(path: '/panel', status: 301)

  # Client part
  devise_for :clients, path: '/panel'

  scope module: :panel, path: '/panel', as: 'panel' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: After adding route for admin namespace i am being redirect to http://localhost:3000/admins/sign_in now. Isn't it possible to have singular convention in devise views of admin section so that URL should look like http://localhost:3000/admin/sign_in/

Comment: Can you please update routes file in the ticket? In my case, it works as expected `/admin/sign_in`

Comment: My mistake sorry. I did not add your code into route file but just added root to: 'home#index' under admin namespace. Just one last question that how would i tell ruby to read admin layout from /app/views/layout/admin/admin.html.erb ?

Comment: One more question, devise admin login form ask to enter email address and password for login. I have created a new field with the name "username" in admin table from command line. What changes will need to make to authenticate admin user by entering username and password?

Comment: For the layout I have: `app/controller/admin/base_admin_controller.rb` and other controllers inherits from it. Then, I have a layout defined in `views/layouts/admin/base_admin.html.erb`
About authentication with username - everything is described in the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

Comment: can you please show the code of your app/controller/admin/base_admin_controller.rb? so you mean to say my admin/home_controller will inheri base_admin_controller.rb.....right?

Comment: can you please show the code of your app/controller/admin/base_admin_controller.rb and app/controller/admin/home_controller.rb

Comment: To be honest I cannot share the whole code, but in general, you have to do something like this: [code](https://gist.github.com/MrShemek/3b1b9a88e7d329a6ac7b981389a77b96)